# Compact specification of a 3-by-n array without rearranging memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I have a `3 x n` numpy array with large `n` that is specified explicitly, e.g.,

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
  [
      +0.000867019185663,
      +0.011660052716448,
      +0.022876936356421,
      +0.030448982673938,
      # [...]
  ], [
      0.500950464352200,
      0.488212957934729,
      0.455136681950283,
      0.455136681950283,
      # [...]
  ], [
      0.600950464352200,
      0.188212957934729,
      0.155136681950283,
      0.188212957934729,
      # [...]
  ]])
```

To make the code more compact, I usually specify `a` as a transpose

```
a = numpy.array([
  [+0.000867019185663, 0.500950464352200, 0.600950464352200],
  [+0.011660052716448, 0.488212957934729, 0.188212957934729],
  [+0.022876936356421, 0.455136681950283, 0.155136681950283],
  [+0.030448982673938, 0.401996259318289, 0.101996259318289],
  # [...]
  ]).T
```

However, this gives me a non-contiguous array. I could certainly make it contiguous via `numpy.ascontiguousarray` (or `transpose()` instead of `T`), but I'd like to avoid rearranging the memory.

Is there a way to specify `a` in compact form while still getting a contiguous array of shape `(3, n)`?

Comment: Is it an option to keep `a` a 1D vector and reshape when needed since `reshape` has an `order ` keyword?

Comment: Make a copy : `a.T.copy()`?

Comment: @percusse I would guess that if you first create an array in memory like `a.T` and then reshape it, then the memory will have to be rearranged.

Comment: @Divakar I would like to avoid memory operations, just like they are unnecessary when specifying `a` as in the first code example.

Comment: Ah what I mean is that you create `a` with `a.reshape(3,n)` and the transpose with `reshape(n,3)` with the right order. So probably it won't cost as much if I remember the details correctly but I'm not sure..

Comment: For a large constant array, why not entirely remove it from your source code and include it as a separate file with `np.save` and `np.load`? as an added benefit, if it's truly massive, and you only ever need small segments at a time, you could specify the `mmap_mode` keyword and leave most of it on disk and not in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the array in Fortran order (column major) it will be C-contiguous after transposing it.

Example:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], order='F').T

# verification
y = np.ascontiguousarray(x)  # should not make a copy if x is contiguous
y[1] = 42  # modify y
print(x)  # x has changed (no copy was made)
```

Counter example:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], order='C').T

# verification
y = np.ascontiguousarray(x)  # should make a copy if x is not contiguous
y[1] = 42  # modify y
print(x)  # x has *not* changed (it was copied into y)
```

---

Remark:

I don't think avoiding memory rearrangement at this stage has much practical value. Initializing an array like this first creates a Python list, which is discarded after copying it to a newly allocated array. One more copy (array to contiguous array) might not be such a big deal...